# How to convert Excel to XML with nested elements using XSLT 1.0?

Tags: xml, excel, xslt, nested

I'm trying to convert an XML structure exported from Excel in a new structure with nested elements.
It's a bit too tricky for me to figure out, how to do so with XSLT v1.0.

My goal is to put the row data into the desired lavel of the result xml.
So if a row contains only 1 cell with data, then it is a category for example:

```
<projects> 
<category name="001">
...
</category>
</projects>
```

If a row has 2 data cells it represents a regions and should be a child of the previos category.

```
<projects> 
<category name="001">
<region name="AAA">...</region>
<region name="BBB">...</region>
</category>
</projects>
```

If the row has 3 or 4 cells with data its represents an account, which should be a child of the previous region.

```
<projects> 
<category name="001">
<region name="AAA">
<account name="lorem">...</account>
<account name="ipsum">...</account>
</region>
<region name="BBB">...</region>
...
</category>
</projects>
```

Ok, what I have so far:
Here's the XML file from Excel. It has a simple structure with repeating row elements.
Each row contains 5 cells, but not every cell always contains a Data element too.
I tried to use this to determine what kind of information each row represents.

```
    <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="6" ss:ExpandedRowCount="69" x:FullColumns="1"    x:FullRows="1" ss:StyleID="s62" ss:DefaultColumnWidth="69">
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="14.25">
    <Cell ss:Index="2" ss:StyleID="s68"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s69"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s68"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s68"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s68"/>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="15">
    <Cell ss:Index="2" ss:StyleID="s70"><Data ss:Type="String">Categorie 004</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s71"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s72"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="14.25">
    <Cell ss:Index="2" ss:StyleID="s68"><Data ss:Type="String">AAA</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s69"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s69"><Data ss:Type="String">X</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s73"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s74"><Data ss:Type="Number">0.01</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="14.25">
    <Cell ss:Index="2" ss:StyleID="s68"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s69"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s68"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s73"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s68"/>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:Height="14.25">
    <Cell ss:Index="2" ss:StyleID="s68"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s69"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s68"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s73"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s68"/>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="14.25">
    <Cell ss:Index="2" ss:StyleID="s68"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s69"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s68"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s73"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s68"/>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="15">
    <Cell ss:Index="2" ss:StyleID="s70"><Data ss:Type="String">Categorie 001</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s71"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s72"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="14.25">
    <Cell ss:Index="2" ss:StyleID="s82"><Data ss:Type="String">AAA</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s83"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s82"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s84"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s85"><Data ss:Type="Number">3.0800000000000001E-2</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="14.25">
    <Cell ss:Index="2" ss:StyleID="s68"><Data ss:Type="String">dolor</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s69"><Data ss:Type="Number">123</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s69"><Data ss:Type="String">A</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s86"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s74"><Data ss:Type="Number">0.01</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="15">
    <Cell ss:Index="2" ss:StyleID="s68"><Data ss:Type="String">sit amet</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s69"><Data ss:Type="Number">445</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s69"><Data ss:Type="String">B</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s86"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s74"><Data ss:Type="Number">0.03</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="14.25">
    <Cell ss:Index="2" ss:StyleID="s68"><Data ss:Type="String">consetetur</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s69"><Data ss:Type="Number">36</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s69"><Data ss:Type="String">B</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s86"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s74"><Data ss:Type="Number">8.0000000000000004E-4</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="14.25">
    <Cell ss:Index="2" ss:StyleID="s82"><Data ss:Type="String">BBB</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s83"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s82"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s84"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s85"><Data ss:Type="Number">0.03</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="14.25">
    <Cell ss:Index="2" ss:StyleID="s68"><Data ss:Type="String">sadipscing</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s69"><Data ss:Type="Number">666</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s69"><Data ss:Type="String">A</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s86"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s74"><Data ss:Type="Number">0.01</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="15">
    <Cell ss:Index="2" ss:StyleID="s68"><Data ss:Type="String">elitr</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s69"><Data ss:Type="Number">97</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s69"><Data ss:Type="String">C</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s86"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s74"><Data ss:Type="Number">0.02</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="15">
    <Cell ss:Index="2" ss:StyleID="s68"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s69"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s68"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s73"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s68"/>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="14.25">
    <Cell ss:Index="2" ss:StyleID="s70"><Data ss:Type="String">Categorie 001</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s71"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s72"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="14.25">
    <Cell ss:Index="2" ss:StyleID="s82"><Data ss:Type="String">AAA</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s83"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s82"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s84"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s85"><Data ss:Type="Number">0.04</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="14.25">
    <Cell ss:Index="2" ss:StyleID="s68"><Data ss:Type="String">aliquyam</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s69"><Data ss:Type="Number">65</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s69"><Data ss:Type="String">A</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s86"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s74"><Data ss:Type="Number">0.02</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="14.25">
    <Cell ss:Index="2" ss:StyleID="s68"><Data ss:Type="String">ipsum</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s69"><Data ss:Type="Number">99</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s69"><Data ss:Type="String">B</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s86"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s74"><Data ss:Type="Number">0.02</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="14.25">
    <Cell ss:Index="2" ss:StyleID="s82"><Data ss:Type="String">BBB</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s83"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s82"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s84"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s85"><Data ss:Type="Number">0.01</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="14.25">
    <Cell ss:Index="2" ss:StyleID="s68"><Data ss:Type="String">lorem</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s69"><Data ss:Type="Number">321</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s69"><Data ss:Type="String">C</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s86"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s74"><Data ss:Type="Number">0.01</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
  </Table>
```

So far I've created the following stylesheet and where able to filter all information as needed.

```
<!-- Filter Excel Cells -->
<xsl:template match="ss:Row">
    <xsl:if test="count(.//ss:Data) &gt; 0">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="count(.//ss:Data)=1">
                <Categorie>
                    <xsl:value-of select=".//ss:Cell[1]/ss:Data"/>
                </Categorie>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="count(.//ss:Data)=2">
                <Region>
                    <xsl:value-of select=".//ss:Cell[1]/ss:Data"/>
                </Region>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="count(.//ss:Data)=3">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test=".//ss:Cell[5]/ss:Data='Rating'">
                        <Header>
                            <Text1>
                                <xsl:value-of select=".//ss:Cell[1]/ss:Data"/>
                            </Text1>
                            <Text2>
                                <xsl:value-of select=".//ss:Cell[3]/ss:Data"/>
                            </Text2>
                            <Text3>
                                <xsl:value-of select=".//ss:Cell[5]/ss:Data"/>
                            </Text3>
                        </Header>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <Account>
                            <Name>
                                <xsl:value-of select=".//ss:Cell[1]/ss:Data"/>
                            </Name>
                            <Value>
                                <xsl:value-of select=".//ss:Cell[3]/ss:Data"/>
                            </Value>
                            <Rating>
                                <xsl:value-of select=".//ss:Cell[5]/ss:Data"/>
                            </Rating>
                        </Account>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="count(.//ss:Data)=4">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test=".//ss:Cell[5]/ss:Data='Gewicht'">
                        <Header>
                            <Text1>
                                <xsl:value-of select=".//ss:Cell[1]/ss:Data"/>
                            </Text1>
                            <Text2>
                                <xsl:value-of select=".//ss:Cell[2]/ss:Data"/>
                            </Text2>
                            <Text3>
                                <xsl:value-of select=".//ss:Cell[3]/ss:Data"/>
                            </Text3>
                            <Text4>
                                <xsl:value-of select=".//ss:Cell[5]/ss:Data"/>
                            </Text4>
                        </Header>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <Account>
                            <Name>
                                <xsl:value-of select=".//ss:Cell[1]/ss:Data"/>
                            </Name>
                            <Type>
                                <xsl:value-of select=".//ss:Cell[2]/ss:Data"/>
                            </Type>
                            <Value>
                                <xsl:value-of select=".//ss:Cell[3]/ss:Data"/>
                            </Value>
                            <Rating>
                                <xsl:value-of select=".//ss:Cell[5]/ss:Data"/>
                            </Rating>
                        </Account>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

My results now looks this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Projects xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
    <Categorie>Categorie 004</Categorie>
    <Region>AAA</Region>
    <Account>
        <Name>AAA</Name>
        <Value>X</Value>
        <Rating>0.01</Rating>
    </Account>
    <Account>
        <Name>Name</Name>
        <Type>Value</Type>
        <Value>Type</Value>
        <Rating>Rating</Rating>
    </Account>
    <Categorie>Categorie 001</Categorie>
    <Region>AAA</Region>
    <Account>
        <Name>dolor</Name>
        <Type>123</Type>
        <Value>A</Value>
        <Rating>0.01</Rating>
    </Account>
    <Account>
        <Name>sit amet</Name>
        <Type>445</Type>
        <Value>B</Value>
        <Rating>0.03</Rating>
    </Account>
    <Account>
        <Name>consetetur</Name>
        <Type>36</Type>
        <Value>B</Value>
        <Rating>8.0000000000000004E-4</Rating>
    </Account>
    <Region>BBB</Region>
    <Account>
        <Name>sadipscing</Name>
        <Type>666</Type>
        <Value>A</Value>
        <Rating>0.01</Rating>
    </Account>
    <Account>
        <Name>elitr</Name>
        <Type>97</Type>
        <Value>C</Value>
        <Rating>0.02</Rating>
    </Account>
    <Account>
        <Name>Name</Name>
        <Type>Value</Type>
        <Value>Type</Value>
        <Rating>Rating</Rating>
    </Account>
    <Categorie>Categorie 001</Categorie>
    <Region>AAA</Region>
    <Account>
        <Name>aliquyam</Name>
        <Type>65</Type>
        <Value>A</Value>
        <Rating>0.02</Rating>
    </Account>
    <Account>
        <Name>ipsum</Name>
        <Type>99</Type>
        <Value>B</Value>
        <Rating>0.02</Rating>
    </Account>
    <Region>BBB</Region>
    <Account>
        <Name>lorem</Name>
        <Type>321</Type>
        <Value>C</Value>
        <Rating>0.01</Rating>
    </Account>
</Projects>
```

Not bad (for me), but I need the data to be nested like this way and not every data in the same level.
I need your help!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Projects xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
    <Categorie name="001"/>
        <Region name="AAA">
            <Account>
                <Name>Name</Name>
                <Type>Value</Type>
                <Value>Type</Value>
                <Rating>Rating</Rating>
            </Account>
            <Account>
                <Name>Name</Name>
                <Type>Value</Type>
                <Value>Type</Value>
                <Rating>Rating</Rating>
            </Account>
        </Region>
        <Region name="BBB">
            <Account>
                <Name>Name</Name>
                <Type>Value</Type>
                <Value>Type</Value>
                <Rating>Rating</Rating>
            </Account>
            <Account>
                <Name>Name</Name>
                <Type>Value</Type>
                <Value>Type</Value>
                <Rating>Rating</Rating>
            </Account>
            ...
        </Region>
        <Categorie name="002"/>
            <Region name="AAA">
                ...
            </Region>
        </Categorie>
</Projects>
```

Answer (score 0):

i believe you need to use element/attribute calls on some of the tags to put them in the format you require such as the below

```
<xsl:element name="Categorie">
        <xsl:attribute name="name">
                 <xsl:value-of select=".//ss:Cell[1]/ss:Data"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:element name="Region">
            <xsl:attribute name="name">
                 <xsl:value-of select=".//ss:Cell[1]/ss:Data"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
          //rest of transform here
        </xsl:element>      
 </xsl:element>
```

I have not ran any sort of test on this yet, but this should point you in the direction you need

Answer (score 0):

Transforming one dimension markup to hierarchy is a grouping problem. In this case a `group-starting-with` problem.

In XSLT 2.0

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="Table">
        <xsl:for-each-group 
            select="Row[.//Data]" 
            group-starting-with="Row[count(.//Data)=1]">
            <Categorie>
                <xsl:for-each-group 
                    select="current-group()[position()>1]" 
                    group-starting-with="Row[count(.//Data)=2]">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="not(self::Row[count(.//Data)=2])">
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <Region>
                                <xsl:apply-templates 
                                    select="current-group()[position()>1]"/>
                            </Region>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
            </Categorie>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Row">
        <Account>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </Account>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Row[.//Cell[5]/Data[.='Rating' or .='Gewicht']]">
        <Header>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </Header>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Data">
        <Data>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </Data>
    </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Outputs:

```
<Categorie>
   <Account>
      <Data>AAA</Data>
      <Data>X</Data>
      <Data>0.01</Data>
   </Account>
</Categorie>
<Categorie>
   <Region>
      <Account>
         <Data>dolor</Data>
         <Data>123</Data>
         <Data>A</Data>
         <Data>0.01</Data>
      </Account>
      <Account>
         <Data>sit amet</Data>
         <Data>445</Data>
         <Data>B</Data>
         <Data>0.03</Data>
      </Account>
      <Account>
         <Data>consetetur</Data>
         <Data>36</Data>
         <Data>B</Data>
         <Data>8.0000000000000004E-4</Data>
      </Account>
   </Region>
   <Region>
      <Account>
         <Data>sadipscing</Data>
         <Data>666</Data>
         <Data>A</Data>
         <Data>0.01</Data>
      </Account>
      <Account>
         <Data>elitr</Data>
         <Data>97</Data>
         <Data>C</Data>
         <Data>0.02</Data>
      </Account>
   </Region>
</Categorie>
<Categorie>
   <Region>
      <Account>
         <Data>aliquyam</Data>
         <Data>65</Data>
         <Data>A</Data>
         <Data>0.02</Data>
      </Account>
      <Account>
         <Data>ipsum</Data>
         <Data>99</Data>
         <Data>B</Data>
         <Data>0.02</Data>
      </Account>
   </Region>
   <Region>
      <Account>
         <Data>lorem</Data>
         <Data>321</Data>
         <Data>C</Data>
         <Data>0.01</Data>
      </Account>
   </Region>
</Categorie>
```

**Do note:** your input is missing namespace declarations for `x` and `ss` prefix (i.e.  `xmlns:x="ns1" xmlns:ss="ns2"`). Also, when grouping with starting pattern the matched element is part of the group (thus `current-group()[position()>1]`) and there might be a first group with all the elements before the first match (thus the `xsl:choose`). The transformation of `Data` elements is left out to better understand the main problem.